# Magento2: How to add product images to custom ui-component admin grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-grid, custom-admin-grid

**I have a custom grid using ui component method in back-end to show data from a custom table with columns as follows:**

```
id 
product_id 
user_id 
store_ids 
status 
adminassign 
created 
modified 
position
```

Here the `product_id`, `user_id`, `status` denotes default `Product ID`, `Customer ID` and `Product Status` respectively. 
Now I have displayed these values in the custom grid.
How can I join the default **catalog_product** and **customer** tables to show more fields like `Product Name`, `Product Image`, `Product Status` and `Customer Name` in to the grid.

**Please help me out. Thank you in advance.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `_initSelect()` method in your `Collection.php` file in your custom module

```
protected function _initSelect()
{
  parent::_initSelect();
  $this->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    ['cp' => $this->getTable('catalog_product')],
    'main_table.product_id = cp.entity_id',
    ['*']
  );
  return $this;
}
```

You can check this module as a reference [link](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-customer-grid-updated-at-field).

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the `Collection` class *Myvendor\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\Pendingproducts\Collection* mentioned in `di.xml`? (like the one in the code below:)
`<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="entity_listing_data_source1" xsi:type="string">Myvendor\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\Pendingproducts\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>`

Comment: Yes, Exactly you need to add this in your **app\code\Myvendor\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\Pendingproducts\Collection.php** file

Comment: I added the _initSelect() method to Collection.php, but it seems like the code is not being run. Because it is not showing anything when I tried to echo the collection query or even added exit() afterwards. Any idea why?

Comment: Please check your **di.xml** file if you've created VirtualType there for collection then we need to add this initselect using dataprovider file.

Comment: ok, I refered your Github module [https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-customer-grid-updated-at-field/blob/master/etc/di.xml]. In there you have updated the dataprovider file.
**<virtualType name="Trust\Marketplace\Model\ResourceModel\Pendingproducts\Collection" type="Trust\Marketplace\Ui\Component\Listing\CustomDataProvider">**
So I guess I need to do that way, right?

Comment: Yes, Right. You can follow this module.. [link](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-customer-grid-updated-at-field). I've added one UI component data provider there. If you do not understand then you can let me know.

Comment: Please check di.xml and this file **https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-customer-grid-updated-at-field/blob/master/Ui/Component/Listing/CustomerDataProvider.php** in that module

Comment: ok, that seems the right way.  
 But it is throwing an error now.
`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hype_malbladna.catalog_product' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `multivendor_product` AS `main_table` LEFT JOIN `catalog_product` AS `cp` ON main_table.product_id = cp.entity_id`

Should the table name be `catalog_product_entity` or something else? But the table does not have the required product information

Comment: Please use **catalog_product_entity** instead of **catalog_product**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101770/discussion-between-coderaiser-and-kishan-savaliya).